# Как поменять горячие клавиши windows?

Tags: windows

Как сменить горячие клавиши на `Windows`.
Хотел `Alt + ←` поменять на клавишу `Ё`
Пробовал копаться в папке `windows` - ничего не нашел.

[image: описание]

Answer (score 0):

Очевидно вы ничего не нашли. Первые 2 ссылки в `google`:

1. https://nastroyvse.ru/opersys/win/pereopredelit-goryachie-klavishi-windows.html
2. https://lumpics.ru/how-change-hotkeys-in-windows-10/

Comment: Бог помощь!!! Решил